# Subscribing To Observable From BehaviorSubject Not Updating Component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to subscribe to an observable that references a BehaviorSubject but when the data is retrieved from the server, it never loads the data from the observable. I can see that it logs from the service, but in my component where I have subscribed to the observable, it does nothing.

I know there are multiple SO threads on this, and I have been through them with no luck at this time. Can someone take a look at this and let me know if they see something glaring?

Thanks,

SERVICE:

```
public dataComplete$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
public dataItem$ = this.dataComplete$.asObservable();
getAsyncRefills(linkToken){
   return this.httpC.get(this.baseUrl + "/AccountInfo/Refills?linkToken=" + linkToken + "&deliveryTypeId=" + 0 + "&pickupLocationId=" + 0 + "&paymentTypeId=" + 0).map((res:Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
       this.asycCollection = res;
        this.dataComplete$.next(Object.assign({},this.asycCollection));
       console.log(this.dataItem$); // This logs an Observable that has a _value property with the data from the http call
    })
}
```

Then here is my COMPONENT:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.buildRefillUsers();
    this.getAddressTypes();
    this.subscription = this.refillService.dataItem$.subscribe(item => {
        if(!item) return;
        console.log(item);
    })
}
```

Comment: which `providers` array you injected `RefillService` object..? NgModule or Component level? You might injected in both place perhaps.

Comment: it is in ngModule. At first it was on the component level, but I saw in another SO that it needs to be at the approot in ngModule, so i moved it there. Still no joy. grr

Comment: I think you should be subscribing to dataComplete$ in your component instead of dataItem$.  Forgive me if you simplified your code for the example, but it seems you should be returning the http.get().map() to your component and not using a BehaviorSubject at all.  BehaviorSubject is both Observable and Observer and doesn't seem appropriate in this situation.

Comment: This demo works fine at least: http://plnkr.co/edit/N3GDgN9WL9bBqIIGs5ih?p=preview

Comment: I've tried that as well. It still never calls the .subscribe() from the component when the large data call is returned. It's weird though, I logout both dataItem$ and dataComplete$ in the service and they both log the data object from the service, but nothing happens in the subscribe() from component.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it working. The component from which I began the call had a reference to the "refillService" in its providers array. After removing that, I get the data returned. But when I leave that route and return, my observable is empty. Shouldn't it stay populated until I tell it to destroy the object?